# Vue js get first value of data model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Id like to get the first returned value of `data.countrys` model as below :

```
...el ...etc..

 data: {

    countrys: [
      {KE : 'KENYA'},
      {USA : 'USA'}

  ] ,


  },
... ready...etc..
```

How can i get the value 'KE' in my method ? below is code am using in my method .

`console.log(vm.$data.$children[0].countrys);`

Comment: (Totally unrelated, but the plural of "country" is "countries".) You'd continue to write normal JS, reach into the `countries` array, and get the key. It's not as easy as it should be, e.g., each country could have `name` and `code` keys, which would make it much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 'KE' is a key, you can use Object.keys function on the object within the 'countrys' array:

```
Object.keys(vm.data.countrys[0])[0];
```

vm.data.countrys[0] will return the {KE : 'KENYA'} object, and then Object.keys will return an array of keys of that object.

Comment: This should work , however am getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: Just checking - Is the data that you are passing to Object.keys definitely not null or undefined?

Comment: The above example only demostrates a set data on countrys , however the real data is got dynamically via resource ajax ans set on the model ,it a vue object model data actually

Comment: is hard to help if you miss that big detail of your question. The source of your data

Comment: Can you confirm using your debugger that the ajax response is returning data with the JSON structure you are expecting, and that the data is being applied to the model correctly?  If you still want troubleshooting help, please post more of your code in your question or via jsfiddle/plunker.

Answer (score 1):

So... `data` is object, `countrys` - array of objects, then result is

```
var country = "KE";
data.countrys[0][country]
```

Comment: The 'KE' is dynamic data , above is just an example

Comment: @JimmyObonyoAbor so use a variable to store your key, I've update answer